# Understanding API routes in Next.js (with App Router)

Tags: rest, next.js13

I'm fairly new to Next.js and I've been following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/H0vhkoXljq0?si=XFXRH54FqWv8JCIm) on creating a ticketing app with Next.js (with App Router) and MongoDB.

The tutorial follows this file structure for the `api` directory where each `route.js` has `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc functions. Here's the link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ClarityCoders/Ticket-Tutorial-App).

```
├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── [id]
│   │   │   ├── route.js
│   │   ├── route.js
```

I understand that the `[id]` directory is used to make API calls to specific tickets, but say I want another query where I get all tickets matching a user. In this case, would I create another [user] directory or should I create another method in the top-level route.js file to handle this? And if the latter how would I name this new method since I feel I should be following the convention of using `GET`, `POST`, etc.

Finally, I would appreciate any additional resources on this topic. I've looked through the official Next.js documentation but they don't seem to cover this since I guess this is more fundamental to do with API creation.